# Retrieving data from 2 table based on given empid in (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I am trying to retrieve data from 2 tables then it is not possible to retrieve. My main intent is for a given id number dis is not possible. I entered an `empid` that id is not going interact with the query if i give the id directly in query this query then the query will be executed directly.

My code is

```
int s1 = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("empid"));  
pstmt.setInt(1,s1);
pstmt=con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM saldetails Natural Join empdetails where empid=s1");
pstmt.executeUpdate();
rs = pstmt.executeQuery() ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of a prepare statement is totally wrong. You need to call `setInt()` ***after*** you prepare the statement. And you have to use `?` for the parameter placeholders.

Additionally you should not run `executeUpdate()` for a `SELECT` statement.

```
int s1 = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("empid"));  
pstmt=con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM saldetails Natural Join empdetails where empid=?");
pstmt.setInt(1,s1);
rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

Please avoid `SELECT *` in production code - especially in queries that join tables.

Your code kind of indicates that you just guessed what to do rather than reading the JavaDocs or any other kind of documentation (e.g. a tutorial) before starting to code. I highly recommend you catch up by reading a decent Java/JDBC tutorial before you continue with your development:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/getstart/GettingStartedTOC.fm.html